# Deep Learning Image for the NIPS Prosthetics Challenge?

Tags: google-dl-platform

Where can I find such an image if it exists?

Secondly does the fact that the challenge has a 3D rendering / video output component mean making such an image would be particularly difficult?

Challenge: https://www.crowdai.org/challenges/nips-2018-ai-for-prosthetics-challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware about images specific for this challenge, however we have different generic DeepLearning images: https://blog.kovalevskyi.com/deep-learning-images-for-google-cloud-engine-the-definitive-guide-bc74f5fb02bc

I hope that one of them might be useful to you. Please let me know if something is missing there that is required for the challenge.